# How do I print a sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

The following code is supposed to sort the array initialized below.

```
int[] intArray = { 32, 42, 1, 23, 56, 75, 32, 23 };
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < intArray.length; j++) {
    if (intArray[j - 1] > intArray[j]) {
      temp = intArray[j - 1];
      intArray[j - 1] = intArray[j];
      intArray[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

What should you type to get the sorted array and where should you type it?

I have tried some options such as `System.out.println(temp)` between the last two closing brackets and the one before those, but I am not getting all the values printed, and `32` is printing many times instead.

Writing the code `System.out.println(j)` or `System.out.println(i)` in the same area doesn't work either. Can you explain why these codes don't work?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is print the sorted array, simply print the elements in a for loop after the array is sorted:

```
for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(intArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code sorts an array, if you print something inside any bracket it will show the process, not the answer.
try to print the array after the last bracket.

```
    int[] intArray={32,42,1,23,56,75,32,23};                
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        for(int j=1; j < intArray.length; j++){
            if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
                temp = intArray[j-1];
                intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                intArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for( int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println(intArray[i]);
    }
```

I'm not a native english speaker so I apologize if there's any grammatical error in my words.